# git log throws error "ambiguous argument"

Tags: windows, git

This used to work about a year ago. Now it doesn't:

```
git log --abbrev=6
```

The expected result would be all commit hashes abbreviated to 6 characters.

The actual result is now this error message:

> fatal: ambiguous argument '6': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
>   Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
>   'git  [...] -- [...]'

I have the impression that Git doesn't even know about that argument and tries to silently ignore its name but not the value.

Using Git 1.8.1.msysgit.1 on Windows 7.

**Addition:** Oh and it fails on other parameters, too. The entire command is:

```
git log --abbrev=6 --format=format:"----- Commit %%h on %%ci by %%an -----%%n%%n%%B"
```

If I just leave the abbrev part out, it still returns another error:

> fatal: Invalid object name 'format'.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the above fail for me but neither do they work, at least not for me on Mac/Unix.

The first error is being thrown because Git is parsing your statement as if `--abbrev` is a unary flag (i.e. does not take an argument) and the `6` is a single object ref (e.g. a branch name, a SHA, etc).  As in:

```
git log --abbrev GITREF    # Like branch or tag '6'
```

It seems to be doing the same thing with the `format` keyword.

My guess is one of the following:

1. Distinctly un-UNIX-like command line parsing in your Windows terminal emulator, which is causing severe mangling of your options
2. A bug in your version of Git that did not affect the base code and hence did not make it into the main Git release notes (I checked...)
3. A possible change in the way `--abbrev` is handled which was omitted from the release notes (Again, I checked...)

Just out of curiosity, let me know if any of the following work (note: I de-duped your percent signs. Was that a Windows thing?):

```
git log --format=format:'----- Commit %h on %ci by %an -----%n%n%B' --abbrev=6
git log --format=format:'----- Commit %h on %ci by %an -----%n%n%B' --abbrev-commit
git log --pretty=format:'----- Commit %h on %ci by %an -----%n%n%B' --abbrev=6
git log --pretty=format:'----- Commit %h on %ci by %an -----%n%n%B' --abbrev-commit
```